# How do I stop NCover from hijacking every .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, ncover

I know that this, strictly speaking, is not a programming question, but I think the only people who can answer it are programmers.

I've never had this happen before, but on one workstation where I have NCover installed, it seems to be intercepting every .NET assembly I load. For example, after installing it, suddenly it takes several minutes to load any .NET application; .NET services fail to start because they time out; NCover itself even takes minutes to load.

What's going on here? I opened Process Explorer to look at some of these and found that my assemblies were referring to NCover DLLs and such, especially pertaining to mscorlib.

Has anyone had this happen before? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like things didn't get cleaned up correctly after running coverage on IIS or a service. Check out HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Environment in your registry. If Cor_Enable_Profiling and Cor_Profiler are there as keys, you're going to want to delete them. Also, you'll want to delete NCover_Pid, NCover_Admin, COMPLUS_ProfAPI_ProfilerCompatibilitySetting, NCover_Process_Module, and NCover_All if they're there.